# How to say you did an action before imagining it

Tags: grammar, imaginary-situations

Consider this sentence:

> If you asked me this question some decades ago, I might answer “Yes or perhaps”

I guess it's wrong and the correct must be:

> if you would have asked me this question some decades ago, I might have answered “Yes or perhaps”

What about:

> Had you asked me this question some decades ago, I might have answered “Yes or perhaps”

It's about a situation that didn't happen in the past and now one express possibilities. Which ones are correct and why?

Comment: If you **had** [whatever], I might **have** answered: past time. If + would is usually not right. Obviously, then, the question is your third sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The last construction seems to be okay (one that has used the 3rd conditional):

[If you had /Had you] asked me this question some decades ago, I [would/could/might] have answered.

PS: I assume that “Yes or perhaps” is not any part of your example-sentences.

"It's about a situation that didn't happen in the past and now one express possibilities. Am I right?" --Yes, it often expresses a feeling of regret of the speaker.

Comment: It can be used to express regret but it may also express growth or a change of opinion.